# document saving despite incorrect input type

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm intentionally inputting numbers for either the firstname or lastname, but document is still saving on the database. my understanding is that it should throw an error instead.

here's my schema

```js
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
  },
  {
    collection: "Users",
  }
);

const User = model("User", userSchema);
```

and my function

```js
async function addUser({ firstName, lastName }) {
  try {
    const newUser = new User({
      firstName: await firstName,
      lastName: await lastName,
    });

    await newUser.save();

    console.log(`${firstName} ${lastName} has registered.`);
  } catch (error) {
    throw console.error(error);
  }
}
```

here's how I call `addUser`

```js
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const firstName = await req.body.firstName;
    const lastName = await req.body.lastName;

    console.log(typeof firstName);
    console.log(typeof lastName);

    addUser({ firstName, lastName });

    res.json({
      firstName,
      lastName,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw console.error(error);
  }
});
```

here's my most recent postman post request

```js
{
    "firstName": 1234,
    "lastName": "test",
    "email": "someemail@gmail.com",
    "password": "abcd1234"
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the numbers are not converted to a string when you are sending them? Could you add an example? You should try something like `addUser({firstName: Number(1), lastName: Number(2)})`

Comment: Can you show us how you call `addUser`? Also why are you `awaiting` the names?

Comment: my req.body.firstName/lastName does log as typeof number.. is that normal behavior?

Comment: i'm new to async await, even async in general... i think i'm await'ing these because they're values coming from the function call... i think maybe that helps?

Comment: added how I call `addUser` on the post

Comment: oh and btw, I'm using Postman, maybe that's the culprit? does Postman convert these values to string, or is it normal behavior anyway in forms

Comment: @TamasSzoke hi I just edited my post to reflect my postman post request at the bottom purposely inputting a number but comes as a string from my `req.body.firstName`

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#strings):

> If you pass an element that has a toString() function, Mongoose will
>   call it, unless the element is an array or the toString() function is
>   strictly equal to Object.prototype.toString().

Since JavaScript's `number` type provides `toString()` this is called, the value is converted to a `string` and there will be no validation error.

Note that you can use a custom validator to prevent the behaviour and to throw an error if the type is not a string:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  firstname: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
      validator: value => typeof value === 'string',        
      message: props => `${props.value} is not of type string!`
    }
  }, ...
```

Also note that you should get rid of the unnecessary `awaits` since your not awaiting a Promise in those cases. You can simply do:

```
const firstName = req.body.firstName;
const lastName = req.body.lastName;
```

and

```
 const newUser = new User({ firstName, lastName });
```

Comment: actually i checked `typeof` of the values right in the req.body[value], and they're already a string. mongoose hasn't touched em yet at that point right?

Comment: That's true, yes. Can you show us your postman/curl request? Seems like you're already sending the values as a string.

Comment: i edited my post to reflect my postman post request showing that I purposely input number for `firstName` yet it comes to my req.body.firstName as already a string...

Comment: Which `content-type` are you using?

Comment: application/json